# groovy console in osgi

Tags: groovy, osgi

I managed to embed the standard groovy console to Felix and expose a number of variables (i.e. BundleContext, etc).

However, on "first" start up of my blueprint bundle, I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.6.0_24]
  ... ... ...
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.callAutoRegisterMethods(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:202)[groovy-all-1.7.8.jar:1.7.8]
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/reflect/ConstructorAccessorImpl
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)[:1.6.0_24]
    ... ... ...
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)[:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)[:1.6.0_24]
    ... ... ...
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:153)[groovy-all-1.7.8.jar:1.7.8]
    at groovy.swing.SwingBuilder.registerActionButtonWidgets(SwingBuilder.groovy:94)[groovy-all-1.7.8.jar:1.7.8]
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: *** Package 'sun.reflect' is not imported by bundle groovy-all [18], nor is there any bundle that exports package 'sun.reflect'. However, the class 'sun.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl' is available from the system class loader. There are two fixes: 1) Add package 'sun.reflect' to the 'org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra' property and modify bundle groovy-all [18] to import this package; this causes the system bundle to export class path packages. 2) Add package 'sun.reflect' to the 'org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation' property; a library or VM bug can cause classes to be loaded by the wrong class loader. The first approach is preferable for preserving modularity. ***
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1782)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)[:1.6.0_24]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteClassLoader.loadClass(CallSiteClassLoader.java:51)[groovy-all-1.7.8.jar:1.7.8]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)[:1.6.0_24]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.loadClass(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:58)[groovy-all-1.7.8.jar:1.7.8]
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl not found by groovy-all [18]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:787)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.0.9.jar:]
    ... 69 more
```

With the exception thrown, my bundle is now active. However, the console do not show. If I stop and start the bundle again, the error no longer shows and i'm able to see and use my swing groovy console.

The stack trace indicates the following options to fix this problem:

1. Add package 'sun.reflect' to the
   'org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra'
   property and modify bundle
   groovy-all [18] to import this
   package; this causes the system
   bundle to export class path
   packages.
2. Add package 'sun.reflect' to the
   'org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation'
   property; a library or VM bug can
   cause classes to be loaded by the
   wrong class loader. The first
   approach is preferable for
   preserving modularity. ***

I am quite certain that with option 2, the error will go away.

However, my question is...if `sun.reflect` is not imported, why does the groovy console show after i restart the bundle? Appreciate advice from anyone with such experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1** is the correct solution to the problem. Your bundle depends on package `sun.reflect`, so you should make that explicit in the Import-Package statement.

I have no idea why the console might show after restarting. It may do its own internal "fail-over" in the event it can't load the `sun.reflect` package. I wouldn't worry too much about this aspect, just get it to work by adding the import.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. Adding "org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=sun.reflect" to the framework's configuration map solved the problem. Strangely, a check in groovy-all's manifest file does not seem to import sun.reflect. Felix debug log indicated this "[Blueprint Extender: 2] felix.wire - DYNAMIC WIRE: [39.0] package; (package=sun.reflect) -> [0]". Would appreciated if anyone knows how to find out more about "dynamic wire".